# Excel VBA: dynamically saving excel sheets into one PDF based on certain criteria in the cell (1 number = 1 sheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I got WB with different number of sheets and with the same structure and so on. There is one field let's say D8 as an example where is written number 3 (CH) and based on that number in that cell, I would like to export exactly that number of sheets into one PDF. So, if it is written five, then five pages into one PDF...or if it is one then one page in PDF.
That cell in D8 will be always on the same position, but the number might differ. Can this be somehow written into the code to look on this number and to export that many sheets into one PDF?

And I would like to have an option where to save every new PDF, not like now that is automatically created, firstly folder and then file.

Here is SS of my WB:
[image]

and this is piece of code what I was using but just to save sheets into single PDF, I am not so good in VBA so any help will be great!

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()

  Dim FolderPath As String

  FolderPath = "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\PDFs"
  MkDir FolderPath
  
  Sheets(Array("CH1", "CH2", "CH3")).Select
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\PDf", _
  openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False

  MsgBox "All PDF's have been exported!"
  End Sub
```

Comment: What should be the meaning of "D8 as an example where is written number 3"? In this case of 3 number, would you like to save the first three sheets of the workbook in discussion? If not, what do you need, in fact? Three sheets of the workbook  is different than the first three workbook sheets... And what do you mean by "to have an option where to save every new PDF"? Do you need a browse window to choose the folder to be used for saving or something else. If something else, please clarify what (only) you have in mind...

Comment: @FaneDuru So, that D8 will be changeable number, I just wrote 3 as an example, but doesn't have to be those 3 sheets, it can minimum 1. Meaning, if I type 5 instead of 3 then I should get 5 sheets in PDF and so on. Those sheets will be filled accordingly, and the purpose is to spare lot of time converting them and then merging into one PDF. The main goal is to recognize which number is given in cell D8 and according to that value, export me that number of sheets into one PDF, nothing else.  
About the saving, I checked your code and it saves as I need, to browse for folder and then save it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask a question, it is recommended to frequently check it and try clarifying the comments asking for clarifications...

If I understood well your question, please test the next code. It assumes that the answer to my suppositions in the comment is yes. The code offers a browse window to select the folder where to export the chosen (`sheetsNo`) number of sheets:

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()
  Dim FolderPath As String, sheetsNo As Long, sh As Worksheet, arrSheets
  Dim fldr As FileDialog, sItem As String, fileName As String, i As Long
 
  sheetsNo = ActiveCell.value 'use there the sheet you need

  ReDim arrSheets(sheetsNo - 1) 'redim the array to keep the sheets
  
  'use a dialog to select the folder to export
  Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder where to export the pdf file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
 End With
NextCode:
 If sItem = "" Then Exit Sub 'if no folder selected the code stops
 
 FolderPath = sItem
  
  fileName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", ".pdf") 'use the workbook name, but changing its extension
  For i = 1 To sheetsNo
    arrSheets(i - 1) = Worksheets(i).Name 'put the sheets in an array
  Next

  Sheets(arrSheets).Select
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=FolderPath & "/" & fileName, _
  openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False

  MsgBox "All PDF's have been exported!"
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Well, as I wrote into comment, this part where you wrote "sheetsNo = 3" that must be dynamic, because it won't be always 3 sheets, this will always differ. I might put number 5 and then I should get 5 sheets into one single PDF.... I tested, seems partly good (saving part is good) but this with "number = sheet" part is still somehow missing. But, big thanks for this!

Comment: @Mirza: This part I considered not so important... But I will update the code to take it from "D7" cell. I understood that it is "an example" and I thought that you will choose what range you need.

Comment: @Mirza: Adapted the code to take the sheets number in discussion from range "D7" of the active sheet. You can change `ActiveSheet` with the sheet you need, if need something else... Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Hmm, well I still have to type in the code the number of sheets I would like... is there any possibility to make it automatic that VBA checks which number is on cell D8, and according to that - to make me the sheets? I am sure we are close, just this manual part is bad, my colleagues won't be happy or better, coding thing is quite another dimension for many of them :D

Comment: sheetsNo = ActiveSheet.Value  gives me an error  error 438  But wait a sec, where in code you defined the cell? I dont see that line...

Comment: No obviously, it gives me an error still.

Comment: Whichever value I take in the sheet that will be the number of sheets (exported)? Gives me an error in 5th line, exactly there "sheetsNo = ActiveSheet.value" ..and when I see in debugger (hover over yellow part) it is written "sheetsNo = 0"

Comment: @Mirza: Ups... i made a stupid mistake and I did not test the code. It should be ActiveCell.Value. And I wrote it twice in comments without seeing what is it about... I could swear it is ActiveCell. I also explaind it being the active cell value... Sorry, I will update the code.

Comment: I guess this will work. Will check it in next two days, but I have to learn this code, to understand it better. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mirza: Do you think that more comments on the code will help? I think I commented all parts in a way to be understandable...

Comment: No no man, comments are great...but coding language for me is unknown, I am not into VBA, maybe just bit basics, so that makes hard to understand. But yeah, it has to be learned. I will mark as an Answer! Thanks!